# Is calumny against the law in Ohio and in British Columbia, Canada?

Tags: criminal-law, canada, defamation, ohio

Calumny is technically the act of a person falsely accusing another person of a crime.

However, the common definition of calumny means the act of maliciously (i.e. with
the intent to do harm) misrepresenting someone's conduct to harm that person's reputation."

Is *calumny* a crime to be charged by a State prosecutor?

Is *calumny* an offense that can be the subject of a civil suit?

What would be the relevant statutes in Ohio? in British Columbia?

Answer (score 6):

In Ohio, and in most common-law jurisdictions, this conduct is covered under the tort of defamation. It is a common law tort rather than a statutory tort, so there is no statute to consult. Case law requires a defamation plaintiff to prove:

1. that a false statement of fact was made;
2. that the statement was defamatory;
3. that the statement was published;
4. that the plaintiff suffered injury as a proximate result of the publication; and
5. that the defendant acted with the requisite degree of fault in publishing the statement.

[*Am. Chem. Soc. v. Leadscope, Inc.*, 133 Ohio St.3d 366, ¶ 77](https://casetext.com/case/american-chemical-society-v-leadscope).

In the United States, defamation is very rarely going to be a criminal matter in and of itself. Because of the First Amendment's robust protections for free speech, defamation cases are generally doomed to failure, even when the speech in question is demonstrably false.

In British Columbia, the elements should be roughly the same, but I don't have a sense of how often these claims are successful or whether there are criminal sanctions for defamation.

Comment: Ohio does have a limited criminal defamation statute punishable by small fines, however, although it contains many limitations. https://codes.ohio.gov/ohio-revised-code/chapter-2739 It is almost never utilized in practice.

Comment: Thank you.  "3. that the statement was published." What about letters secretely circulated?

Comment: * privately circulated

Comment: That would probably still be a publication.

Comment: @Maria Alaniz In defamation actions, unlike in copyright actions "publication" includes any distribution of the statemented to a third person, provided that it was not done  in confidence. See https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/70220/how-is-publication-different-in-copyright-and-defamation-cases

Comment: Defamation is a statement that injures a third party's reputation. The tort of defamation includes both libel (written statements) and slander (spoken statements).

Elements
"To prove prima facie defamation, a plaintiff must show four things: 1) a false statement purporting to be fact; 2) publication or communication of that statement to a third person; 3) fault amounting to at least negligence; and 4) damages, or some harm caused to the person or entity who is the subject of the statement."

Comment: "Truth is widely accepted as a complete defense to all defamation claims."

Answer (score 3):

[ohio](/questions/tagged/ohio)

As well as defamation, covered by @bdb484, "falsely accusing another person of a crime" is also a first degree misdemeanor:

[Ohio Revised Code 2921.13](https://law.justia.com/codes/ohio/2011/title29/chapter2921/section2921-13/) states:

> (A) No person shall knowingly make a false statement, or knowingly swear or affirm the truth of a false statement previously made, when any of the following applies:
>
> [...]
>
> - (2) The statement is made with purpose to incriminate another.
>
> [...]

[british-columbia](/questions/tagged/british-columbia)

The [Candian Criminal Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criminal_Code_(Canada)) codifies most criminal offences in Canada including, at [RSC 1985, c C-46 s.140](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/c-46/section-140.html) the offence of Public Mischief:

> (1) Every one commits public mischief who, with intent to mislead, causes a peace officer to enter on or continue an investigation by
>
> - (a) making a false statement that accuses some other person of having committed an offence;
> - (b) doing anything intended to cause some other person to be suspected of having committed an offence that the other person has not committed, or to divert suspicion from himself;
> - (c) reporting that an offence has been committed when it has not been committed; or...
>
> [...]

Comment: What about lies circulated by email among commercial middle-men with evident  purpose to punish and exclude (black-list) a former supplier (since 1995) from participating in the market for "socially responsible" jewelry? Would ironclad proof of that noxious practice be sufficient to charge calumny? A small fine would be salutary.